# I can't remove the margin with <li>

Tags: html, css, html-lists, margin

Do you know why I can't remove the margin from my `<li>` elements? The browser always adds the specific margin for my list, even when I write the code a specific margin. Here is the CSS and HTML code:

```
#NavLeftList {
    height: 57 % ;
    width: 15 % ;
    position: absolute;
    top: 23 % ;
    border-style: none;
    background: url(images / heaven.jpg);
    margin: 0px
}

#NavLeftList ul {
    margin-left: 11 % ;
}

#NavLeftList ul li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 170px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 1px;
}

#NavLeftList li a {
    height: 35px;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: url(images / tabright.gif);
    display: block
}

#NavLeftList li a span {
    padding: 0px
}

#NavLeftList li a: hover {
    color: #7EC0EE;
}
```

I haven't pasted the HTML code here since it was appearing strangely.

Comment: Post your HTML using the code format. See the FAQ.

Comment: @Frank1985: this behavior is specific to Chrome? IE and FF render as expected?

Comment: You can’t include arbitrary markup in stack overflow posts. Use a sandbox like [Dabbler](http://dabbler.org/) and/or put the code inline in a code block.

Comment: @Sidnicious, but no one would want to _read_ it if it were all marked up. That's what the [four-spaces markdown formatting is for](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code): select all the code that should be formatted as code, then push the helpful `{}` button.

Answer (score 9):

What you’re seeing isn’t a margin on the `li`s, it’s padding on the `ul`.

Zero out the `ul`’s padding.

Comment: @Frank1985 Great! Glad I could help. When an answer works for you, click the little checkmark button next to it to “close” the question and mark it as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

try `list-style-position:inside;` on the `li`.  It's probably leaving space that would be filled by the bullet even though you've set `list-style-type:none;`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
body{margin: 0;}
```

or find the containing element for NavLeftList and set that element's margin to 0 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try following CSS for UL

```
ul { list-style: none; }
```

Comment: This is an attempt to answer and should not be deleted via LQP.  (Feel free to downvote if you don't like it.)

Answer (score -2):

Try making use of a reset.css file which will reset all "default" (and thus different) implementations of paddings and margins in the different browsers.

Example: [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)